# What are these advisory notice items - are they serious?

Tags: peugeot

I am going to see a car and I have just checked the MOT history.
I know nothing about cars, other than they either move... or don't.

When I check the MOT (It passed), I see that there are two issues:

- Test date 11 January 2017
- Expiry date10 January 2018
- Test Result Pass
- Odometer reading 63,240 miles
- MOT test number 5857 0071 1330
- Advisory notice item(s)

  - Exhaust has a minor leak of exhaust gases BACK BOX (7.1.2)
  - Oil leak ()

What do the "Advisory notice item(s)" mean? Are they serious? The car in question is a PEUGEOT 107 and is selling for £2000.

Comment: An Advisory is an item which hasn't failed enough to cause a test failure, but something that needs to be addressed in the near future. The car is safe to drive (and purchase), but will need some minor work.

Answer (score 1):

The advices given are minor issues, but they should be fixed as soon as possible. The exhaust leak if left unattended for long can cause carbon deposits inside engine block. The oil leakage will cause loss of oil and if it becomes severe, engine damage can occur.
So try to fix both issues sooner than later